# automatically compile less file on save of a imported less file

Tags: css, compilation, less

I have split my less/css into several files grouped by certain categories, so the single files stay easy to maintain. Though I only want to have one css file which gets imported into the layout.

For this I have - how I call it - a master less file which imports all the others like config, forms, layout and so on.

Now the problem is, that for example WinLess or all the other copilers i tried, only monitor the save of my master file, and only then compiles it. However this is stupid, because this file nearly never gets any changes. So what I would like to have is something, that detects changes on the imported less files and then only compiles the master file.

Does anyone know any tools, which are capable of that?
Or how do you manage your less files to bypass this problem?

Further Info: I have mapped the server directory locally via SSH and edit the files in there, i.e. the files are only pseudo local. They are on the server but accessible with a local path over a drive letter. The compiler should be able to work with that setup.

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all honesty, your best bet is to actually use Less's own compiler which will of course be the most up to date option. It will be done through command line but it's the best way to know that everything is correct, working and up-to-date.

All the information can be found in the [Less Documentation Here](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage)

More information about compiling with imports can be found [HERE](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options)

The latest version of WinLESS does report that it has automatic re-compiling when an `@import` file is changed so it could be that your version of WinLESS is out of date. (See [HERE](http://winless.org/) - 3rd bullet point under Features)

Alternatively, see if you can get it to work on purely local files. If this works, it may be an issue with the compiler not being able to do asynchronous checks over SSH.

Comment: You were right, my WinLess did not update on its own, for unknown reasons. The new feature is awesome! Thanks for the info. I was using Sshfs Manager, and this seamed to cause the problem. Now I am using ExpanDrive trial which works like a total charm.

I guess the first solution you mentioned would be very solid. However i think I am to stupid to set that all up, at least on windows. :/

Comment: It takes a little bit of work installing ruby and making sure everything matches up. Using non-3rd party in most cases is always best.

Answer (score 0):

I use Notepad++ with the NppExec-plugin on-save script.  If you make a convention decision to always name your primary file "master.less" you can use this script:

```
NPP_CONSOLE 0
NPP_SAVE
if  $(EXT_PART) != .less goto end
"C:\Node.JS\node_modules\.bin\lessc.cmd" -x  "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\master.less" > "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\master.min.css"
:end
```

You can do something similar with any editor that supports batch scripting (like Stewartside suggests)